# Solve the error "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code is view all the data in the gridview

Web.config code is

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConStr" connectionString="DataSource=.;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial catalog=sshopping"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

It is coded in external class

```
namespace DBAction
{
    public class ViewAction
    {
        public DataSet GetAllData()
        {
                SqlCommand cmd = DataConnection.GetConnection().CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "Select UserName,Password,RoleName,EmailID,SecurityQuestion,SecurityAnswer,LastLogin from LoginInfo";
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();  
                da.Fill(ds);
                cmd.Dispose();
                DataConnection.CloseConnection();
                return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

it is giving error in line `da.Fill(ds)`
The code to bind data source with gridview is coded on page load like this.

```
 DataSet ds = new ViewAction().GetAllData();
        gvLoginInfo.DataSource = ds;
        gvLoginInfo.DataBind();
```

And conectionstring code in data connection class is

```
 public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
        {

            if (con == null)
            {
                con = new SqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString;
                con.Open();
            }

             return con;
        }
```

And one one error is

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'datasource'.

Source Error:


Line 19:             {
Line 20:                 con = new SqlConnection();
Line 21:                 con.ConnectionString =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString;
Line 22:                 con.Open();
Line 23:             }
```

Comment: ...and you have an empty Exception block. Check that out before going to all this trouble of asking what the error is.

Comment: Can you post your connection string from your web.config file?

Comment: yes sir i have posted @asafrob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the Web.Config only. Please put one space between DataSource in connectionString as: Data Source. Thus your connection String will become:

```
 "Data Source=.;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial catalog=sshopping".
```

Answer (score 4):

From the examples i see online, in your connection string replace "DataSource" with "Data Source" (with a space between the two words).
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156450.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same error, even after made all changes you mentioned above. 
And after that, I change my code in that way:

My Web.Config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="conStr" connectionString="Data Source=SomeDS;Initial Catalog=SomeCatalog;User Id=myId;Password=myPass" />
</connectionStrings>
```

My old Code:

```
string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString;


        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString ))
        {
            var result= sqlConnection.Query<My_Class>("MY_PROC_NAME", new { count }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            return result;
        }
```

My newCode:

```
var dt = new DataTable();

                using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString ))
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("MY_PROC_NAME", cnn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cnn.Open();
                    var sqlReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (sqlReader.HasRows)
                        dt.Load(sqlReader);

                    cnn.Close();
                }
                result = dt.DataTableToList<My_Class>();
```

DataTableToList is a converter method, if you need i can share it, too.